# In what temporary directory does MediaWiki/Apache store the files?

Tags: php, apache, mediawiki

As you know, files being uploaded to MediaWiki hosted on Apache (or any other HTTPD) will be cached during upload process somewhere (not their final destination, determined by media wiki).

I thought it might be
 /tmp
so I greped the php source, but without any result. It has to be some other temporary directory.

My question is, where does Media Wiki using Apache store the files being uploaded during upload process?

Comment: LocalSettings.php Isn't the directory listed in there somewhere?

Comment: There is _Set $wgCacheDirectory to a writable directory on the web server to make your wiki go slightly faster._ But I do not think that it. It is for cache using on freq. often used content, only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upload temporary directory is determined by the PHP [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) configuration setting, not by the application.

Comment: And where are they stored (what is system default dir), if this is value isnt set? - /tmp?

Comment: Read the linked page: "If not specified PHP will use the system's default." (Usually `/tmp`.)